# Multi cursor editing in multiple (open) documents

Tags: sublimetext3, text-editor

I have 10-20 configuration files in which I have to change the same setting quite often.

I was thinking about multi cursor approach (like in Sublime Text), but in multiple documents at the same time.

I can use find/replace in files, etc, but I would love to see what is being edited and selecting same 'setting key' just by pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> would be just amazing.

Anyone knows an editor which can do multi-cursor editing in multiple buffers/documents? Or maybe another way of efficiently editing multiple files which are almost identical?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Sublime, nor any other editor of which I'm aware. In Sublime, for example, you can have multiple open files in different tabs and/or windows, but only one has the focus at any one time. It just doesn't make much sense to have input going to multiple windows at once.

Your problem is just crying out for a scripted solution. In Sublime you can create macros and Python-based plugins, as well as using regex-based search and replace. If you're using a shell like bash with access to the standard array of command-line utilities, you can use any number of ways (sed, awk, Python, Perl, expect, and many more) to identify the desired files, select the setting that needs to be changed, and change it, either automatically or with confirmation at each step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of sed, perl, awk, etc. I sometimes use that. In my case multi cursor + multi doc would be just a great help :)